# Dependency issue when publish a MAUI application for Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, maui, windows-store, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 MAUI application which is already published in the Google Store and Amazon Store and the Windows version is running locally.

The structure of the solution is quite simple: I have the main project with the majority of the code and then a library of a few functions (I don't think it matters but I created a test project on this function library). This library is added to the project for all platforms.

[image]

When I run the process to *Publish* the application to the Windows Store via Visual Studio 17.8.3 both in *Debug* and *Release* mode, I get this error

> Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'mypath\LanguageInUse.ValidationLogic.dll'

The project file of this library is quite basic

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I cleaned the solution, restored packages (also from PowerShell manually), built and rebuilt the solution but no luck.

Comment: Publish installs the libraries that are used by the build machine and installs the libraries into the publish machine.  When the libraries change (version updates) the new libraries must also be installed in deploy machine.  When you code changes (libraries do not) then the code just need to be copied from build to deploy machine.  The solution depends on what you did to originally did to deploy the application.  How did you originally deploy Net and Maui?

Comment: The library is part of the project. I have never published only the library in the machine. Plus, I'm trying to create the MSIX for the publish on the Microsoft Store.

Comment: You library is calling other standard Net libraries that have been updated.  It is the Net libraries that need to be updated.